# Is it possible to emulate device other than Cisco and Juniper in GNS3 or any other environment?

Tags: lab

For testing and research purposes, I know it is possible to emulate Cisco devices (with dynamips) and Juniper ones (via an "Olive", a FreeBSD based system running on qemu) in a GNS3 environment.

Is it possible to emulate other vendor devices (like Brocade ones) in GNS3 or else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I recommend is to setup a virtualized environment. Either through Vmware workstation or preferably ESXi with vSphere if you have a server to spare. That gives you a very flexible solution.

```
Add a VM for Dynamips
Add Olives if you like
Add ASA either via Dynamips or separately
Add the Cisco CSR1000v VM
Add a VM for Arista
```

That makes it easy to run inter vendor labs and you can connect them through the VM network which makes it simple to setup. I have a lab like this now and it's hosted by a friend so a VPN in to a box he setup (virtual) which is my GW. Then I can configure vSphere and anything I like and run it on the server.

If you have a powerful laptop which 8GB RAM or more you can run a lot of stuff directly on your laptop. Most of these things are RAM heavy but not that heavy for the CPU.

Answer (score 3):

It's like the site says:

- Dynamips, the well known Cisco IOS emulator.
- VirtualBox, runs desktop and server operating systems as well as Juniper JunOS.
- Qemu, a generic open source machine emulator, it runs Cisco ASA, PIX and IPS.

http://www.gns3.net/

you can use these to setup a lab-network.

You can emulate the following hardware :

http://www.gns3.net/hardware-emulated

Comment: So in answer to the original question, does that mean that it is not possible to emulate other vendors in GNS3?

Comment: I see that juniper is also possible:

http://www.gns3.net/hardware-emulated

Comment: You have simply explained the possibilities with GNS3, consider expanding as per the OPs question to other vendors.

Comment: @CraigSirkin "it depends". If the other vendors OS can be run in VirtualBox or Qemu, then you can emulate them. i.e. if they have a virtualized appliance(Which they'll likely advertize as being able to run in VMWare, bt Qemu or VirtualBox usually works too), that'll work - but must don't provide that. e.g. you could get Arista and Vyatta in there, but likely not HP.